# PHP Decoding JSON - Null Output

Tags: php, json

I have probably spent all day trying to figure this out. I have read multiple questions here on stack and also have been reading articles and checking on documentation, but I can't seem to figure out why this batch of code just produces a null output. Am I missing brackets, calling something wrong, ect?

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4879890&units=imperial";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str);
$temp =  $json['main']['temp_min'];
$content = $temp;


$array = array(
     "content" => $content,
      refresh_requency => 30

);


echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Again what I'm asking is can someone point out to me or tell me what I'm doing wrong. Is it my server that's just not handling the data correctly? That could be a possibility.

One other thing I've tried is to just print out `$temp` and/or the other variable like `$str`. When I do that though they don't even show up so that's what I think my problem is just not sure how to fix it.

**Update**

I've come to the conclusion that it's my web hosting service. As if I add `var_dump($json)` I get a null output `null` output.

Also to confirm that its my webhost if I run `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` it points to the file php.ini not allowing outgoing connections. I edited that same file on my local home server(raspberry pi) ran the same file and it works fine.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php read the arguments for the `json_decode()`, if you want to decode as an array, set the 2nd argument to true.

Answer (score 1):

Access $temp like this

```
$temp =  $json->main->temp_min;
```

you will get the desired output.

Also, you need to allow `allow_url_fopen` in your `php.ini` config file. Some hosts disallow it for security reasons

Comment: Actually I've tried that now that you suggested and I had tried it earlier and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Nope no content. I'm assuming this is a problem with my web host provider.

Comment: So you need to allow  allow_url_fopen in your php.ini config file

Comment: I don't have access to that. Time for support tickets

Comment: I guess you need not look for server configuration, just correct your code and things will be running for you.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working solution for your above code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4879890&units=imperial";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$temp =  $json['main']['temp_min'];
$content = $temp;


$array = array(
     "content" => $content,
      "refresh_requency" => 30

);


echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

---

When I executed your code, I found 2 problem into your code snippet:

1) You were trying to use object of type stdClass as array.

Solution:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4879890&units=imperial";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str);
$temp =  $json->main->temp_min;
$content = $temp;


$array = array(
     "content" => $content,
      "refresh_requency" => 30

);


echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

2) You did not put array key into quotes:

```
$array = array(
     "content" => $content,
      refresh_requency => 30

);
```

It should be :

```
$array = array(
     "content" => $content,
      "refresh_requency" => 30

);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

You need second argument to convert json string into associative array instead of the object. And you are trying to use array (`$json['main']['temp_min']`), not object. Also

```
$array = array(
     "content" => $content,
     "refresh_requency" => 30
);
```

The code looks like

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4879890&units=imperial";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$content = $json['main']['temp_min'];

$array = array(
 "content" => $content,
 "refresh_requency" => 30
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

And result is http://codepad.viper-7.com/euBNAk :

```
{"content":44.6,"refresh_requency":30}
```

Comment: Again I've add `$str, true)` on there before and it didn't make a difference then or now.

Comment: Must be my server as a commenter on another answer suggest var_dump($json) and that produces a NULL output. Not sure what's wrong with my webhosting service then.

Comment: Is that a free hosting? They do not allow outgoing connections.

Comment: Nope Paid. I've tried on both my domains one hosted by Dreamhost another by Ipage

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after `<?php` tag.

Comment: I can confirm after adding the `error_reporting` that it is my web host provider not allowing a `allow_url_fopen` in my php.ini file. As if I run the same file from my home server(raspberry pi) it works fine, but I had to edit my php.ini file.

Comment: @pears456 than you have to use cURL or direct connection through the fsockopen

Comment: is that in php? This is all trying to get a print out of certian data in json from php to access it in another application. Can you point me in the right dirrection?

Comment: @pears456 yes, it is php. cURL extension might be not enabled, but fsockopen is a native method. Look, for example, here http://codular.com/curl-with-php or http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/

Comment: I was able to edit my php.ini file I just had to find it deep inside of my control panel. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of json_decode() is assoc (associative). By default it is 0. When it is 0 (default) the json_decode() will return an object, not an array. That's why you are unable to access temp_min by using $json['main']['temp_min'];

However If you use with the value 1 as second parameter, the function will return an array. Parameter 1 means setting associative to 1 (true). So use $json = json_decode($str, true); instead of $json = json_decode($str);. You will be able to access with $json['main']['temp_min']; now.

Also you forgot double quote on line 13 (refresh_requency). Goodluck.

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4879890&units=imperial";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str, true);

$temp =  $json['main']['temp_min'];
$content = $temp;


$array = array(
    "content" => $content,
    "refresh_requency" => 30
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want help

I change your code like this and that be correctly

```
<?php
    $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=4879890&units=imperial";
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($str, TRUE);    // Wrong here
    $temp =  $json['main']['temp_min'];
    $content = $temp;

    $array = array(
       "content" => $content,
       "refresh_requency" => 30         // And wrong here, it's must string
    );

    echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

More information about json decode in php to array or object http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php